# preg_match doesnt allow greek chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please see my reg ex below:

```
$teststring="αβγδεζηθΙκΛμ";

if(!preg_match("/^[A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ0-9\- ]+$/", $teststring))
{
    echo "invalid char";
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please post your real code

Comment: May want to use [unicode points](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) to avoid encoding issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several overlapping character ranges, and it looks like you're trying to test the entire string to make sure it *doesn't* match ONLY those characters? You're going to get quite a few false negatives that way. This could work if you return "success" on a successful `preg_match`, but still a really backwards way of doing it.

Also, if you want to match unicode characters, you'll need the `/u` modifier in order to treat the string as `UTF-16`. You could also use a [Unicode range or block](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) in place of the extensive range if you like; you'll still need `/u`.

Working expression, which will allow the string to be valid if ALL of its characters are only in that range:

```
<?php

$teststring="ΑαβγδεζηθΙκΛμ";
if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9α-ωΑ-Ω ίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ-]+$/u", $teststring))
//                                           ^ note the unescaped hyphen is an
//                                             actual hyphen not a char range
{
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "invalid char";
}

?>
```

You'll also notice if you try it without the `/u` modifier, you'll get the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset {line_num}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to use semicolons:

```
<?php

$teststring="αβγδεζηθΙκΛμ";

if (!preg_match("/^[A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ0-9\- ]+$/", $teststring)) {
    echo "invalid char"; # Semicolon was missing from here
}
else {
    echo "success"; # Semicolon was missing from here
}
```

http://ideone.com/Ylmh0H

Comment: thanks it works with the input that I have provided , however strangely enough if you try using it with certain string its fails and not sure why ... eg: http://ideone.com/8bJkkh

Comment: It looks like that is working as intended, since the success condition is when it does not match: `if (!`